# D3.js based map | Zooming

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, openstreetmap

I have a D3.js based map. Tiles loading from openstreetmap.

My Code:

```
d3.geo.tile=function(){function t(){var t=Math.max(Math.log(n)/Math.LN2-8,0),h=Math.round(t+e),o=Math.pow(2,t-h+8),u=[(r[0]-n/2)/o,(r[1]-n/2)/o],l=[],c=d3.range(Math.max(0,Math.floor(-u[0])),Math.max(0,Math.ceil(a[0]/o-u[0]))),M=d3.range(Math.max(0,Math.floor(-u[1])),Math.max(0,Math.ceil(a[1]/o-u[1])));return M.forEach(function(t){c.forEach(function(a){l.push([a,t,h])})}),l.translate=u,l.scale=o,l}var a=[960,500],n=256,r=[a[0]/2,a[1]/2],e=0;return t.size=function(n){return arguments.length?(a=n,t):a},t.scale=function(a){return arguments.length?(n=a,t):n},t.translate=function(a){return arguments.length?(r=a,t):r},t.zoomDelta=function(a){return arguments.length?(e=+a,t):e},t};

var width = Math.max(900, window.innerWidth),
    height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight),
    prefix = prefixMatch(["webkit", "ms", "Moz", "O"]);

var tile = d3.geo.tile()
    .size([width, height]);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator();

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scale(1 << 14)
    .scaleExtent([1 << 9, 1 << 23])
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var map = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "map")
    .style("width", width + "px")
    .style("height", height + "px")
    .call(zoom)
    .on("mousemove", mousemoved);

var layer = map.append("div")
    .attr("class", "layer");

var info = map.append("div")
    .attr("class", "info");

zoomed();

function zoomed() {
  var tiles = tile
      .scale(zoom.scale())
      .translate(zoom.translate())
      ();

  projection
      .scale(zoom.scale() / 2 / Math.PI)
      .translate(zoom.translate());

  var image = layer
    .style(prefix + "transform", matrix3d(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
    .selectAll(".tile")
    .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; });

  image.exit()
      .remove();

  image.enter().append("img")
      .attr("class", "tile")
      .attr("src", function(d) { return "http://" + ["a", "b", "c"][Math.random() * 3 | 0] + ".tile.osm.org/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .style("left", function(d) { return (d[0] << 8) + "px"; })
      .style("top", function(d) { return (d[1] << 8) + "px"; });
}

function mousemoved() {
  info.text(formatLocation(projection.invert(d3.mouse(this)), zoom.scale()));
}

function matrix3d(scale, translate) {
  var k = scale / 256, r = scale % 1 ? Number : Math.round;
  return "matrix3d(" + [k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, 0, 0, 0, k, 0, r(translate[0] * scale), r(translate[1] * scale), 0, 1 ] + ")";
}

function prefixMatch(p) {
  var i = -1, n = p.length, s = document.body.style;
  while (++i < n) if (p[i] + "Transform" in s) return "-" + p[i].toLowerCase() + "-";
  return "";
}

function formatLocation(p, k) {
  var format = d3.format("." + Math.floor(Math.log(k) / 2 - 2) + "f");
  return (p[1] < 0 ? format(-p[1]) + "°S" : format(p[1]) + "°N") + " "
       + (p[0] < 0 ? format(-p[0]) + "°W" : format(p[0]) + "°E");
}
```

My jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ivanzi/3a6rr/

My question:

Something wrong with zooming... 
I can't zoom to see building numbers like here: http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/49.19680/16.60995

Thanks.

Comment: You should just need to adjust the scaleExtent.

Comment: How? Doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: You give two numbers to `.scaleExtent()`. These denote the minimum and maximum scale. If you want to be able to zoom in further, you need to increase the maximum scale.

Comment: Changed to: .scaleExtent([1 << 7, 1 << 25])

Comment: But on the last zoom level map is blank!? http://jsfiddle.net/ivanzi/3a6rr/

Comment: Works fine up to 1 << 25 for me. After that I'm guessing that the tile server doesn't have any more detailed tiles.

Comment: Doesn't work. Last zoom level (Building numbers) is blank...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52584/discussion-between-user889349-and-lars-kotthoff)